# Jquery-ui library will not loaded/served by Google CDN from the Google site "insert html box"

Tags: google-apps-script

For the past 3 months I have been struggling with the Google sites "insert html box" to get the CDN to serve the Jquery user interface library-jqueryui- without any success.

I have used the following code and its variants without any themes but to no avail;

The jquery library loads fine but not the jqueryui library. The Google developer site suggests that this should work, but I only get these error messages -  failed to load external url jquery-ui.css OR folding element body into parent

What am I doing wrong?? Getting frustrated here!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a known bug. Take a look [at the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615179/jquery-ui-library-not-loaded-served-by-google-cdn-from-the-google-site-insert-h)

There is a bug link to the actual issue and a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [hint about jQuery not always working in HTML boxes](http://n8henrie.com/2014/08/versions-of-jquery-that-work-on-google-sites-html-box/), I experimented and found that *some* versions of jQuery UI will load!

As of today, I was able to load the following versions:

1.8.21,
1.8.20,
1.8.18

or, using the direct links to Googleapis:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

All other versions mentioned on https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/ would not load.

That being said, I encountered more trouble when trying to link to the CSS themes. I couldn't find any way to get an HTML box to accept links to `googleapis` hosted jQuery UI CSS files.

I tried pasting the CSS directly into the HTML box, but the `url()` links to images are not kosher. Commenting them out resulted in my getting the HTML box editor to be at peace, but the attempt to make [tabbed panes](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) work was not successful.

To say that one can do jQuery inside a Google Site is almost an exaggeration.