# jQuery-ui library not loaded/served by Google CDN from the Google site "insert html box" tool

Tags: google-apps-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery-ui library will not loaded/served by Google CDN from the Google site “insert html box”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614768/jquery-ui-library-will-not-loaded-served-by-google-cdn-from-the-google-site-ins)

I am struggling with the Google sites "insert html box" tool to get the CDN to serve the jQuery user interface library — jQueryUI — without any success.

I have used the following code and its variants without any themes but to no avail;

```
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The jQuery library loads fine but not the jQueryUI library. The Google developer site suggests that this should work, but I only get error messages — "failed to load external url jquery-ui.css" or "folding element body into parent".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Bug filed [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1549), which you can track. It will get fixed in Sites a week or two after it is marked fixed on that tracker.

Comment: And.. a workaround has been posted there. Put some HTML, any HTML - it doesn't matter, even just <span></span> before the script. The bug should be fixed, but in the meantime this should get you going.